# How to update a row without using ID in REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

[image: SharepPoint list]

The above image is my sharePoint list,
I want to update the row where year is 2016 and month is 8 without using Item ID
I have tried using PATCH method but the following error occurs:

```
The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP PATCH method.
```

But when i used Item ID my PATCH method Worked.

Comment: in which way do you want to update the columns? Month = 8 = August? And Year without the "," ?

Comment: I want to update Days column where year = 2016 and month = 8

Comment: You can use a calculated column to get e.G. 2016-8. If this is not what you want please give us a little more details about the list columns and the exact output you want in that column.

Comment: My question is can we update a row without using ID ? OR with using other column such as Year and Month

Comment: Use a REST call to find the item ($filter) Then use the ``__metadata.uri`` property from the result to target the item(s) with a REST POST

Comment: Can you show some example or a link where row is updated without using Item ID